# Unity3D - Line Renderer Cannot See Distance With Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a line renderer to act like a grappling cable for a vehicle of mine in my game. It seems, however, from the camera view the line is only visible up to a certain distance far away. Is there anything I can do to make the camera see more of the line?

[image]

EDIT: I should clarify, I know how to extend the length of the line, I have that script written. What I'm saying is that the line is hard to see from the camera when looking from behind. I want to give the player a good idea of how far the hook is going, even when it's over 30 units away on the forward z axis?

FURTHER:

When I turn my car to the side while moving with the line extended a distance, I can see much more of the line since I start to see the line from the side???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super experienced with unity's linerenderer. However it looks like the linerenderer stops at your pink light barrier. I'm not sure if the linerenderer works like a raycast however.

EDIT:
Ok. Now I get what you want to achive. My guess is that unity does not render the line because it becomes smaller than a pixel and the lineRenderer is not a 3D element. I had some succes by using a different curve. Try to increase the width of the line the further away it is.

[image]

Comment: I'd think the same thing - that seemed like a promising answer, but moving my vehicle further out into the track away from the gate still shows similar behavior - basically, I can only see the shadow of my line extend up to about 40 units away, and the line itself only a little above 25 on the z axis

Answer (score 0):

line renderer is a line between two points.
you just need to adjust the values under 'Positions'.
you can also click on the three dot icon at the top to 'edit points in scene view' and drag the further point outward, you can also add points with the plus icon beside it.
you could also use raycast for your grappling hook

Comment: Thanks for your answer - please see the now revised post.